# Accessing chars from 'strings' that aren't declared in a variable (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, char

```
char i;
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    printf("%c","asdf"[i]);
i=1;
if("123"[i]==1)
    i=1;
if("456"[4]==1)
    i=1;
if("789"[1]==1)
    i=1;
```

The output is:

```
asdf 123 456
```

Seemingly most of the 'strings' are directly after each other in the memory. I don't think that this is randomly, or is it?
Moreover, the program fails when I use an int variable instead of i in an char-access-expression, which is not the first (here asdf[i]). e.g. if("123"[j]==1)

Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: The compiler will typically collect all constant strings into a "string table". It may de-duplicate strings when doing that; e.g: "hello\0" and "lo\0" may end up collapsed in the string table.

Comment: But why is "789" not on this table then? How is this depending on the access index, or does it just seem to be so?

Comment: @user1329846: It could be that the compiler calculated `"789"[1]` at compile time but didn't do so for `"456"[4]`. The location of strings in memory is not defined by the C standard, so there are no guarantees about anything here, which is why you should avoid what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constant strings are often stored separately from the program code, and it's not surprising that they are arranged close together in memory. However you should not rely on this.

Your program has **undefined behaviour** and something different could happen if you try to run your code using a different compiler. For example, when I run your code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/DxRXD) using gcc 4.3.4 it doesn't output the same as what you get.

Comment: Sorry to be that dithery, but actually I still want to understand why not all of the strings in my example are directly after each other respectively how that depends on the access index (e.g. i). Especially: Why does the program fail by using int for this index?

Comment: @user1329846: One of the cool things about undefined behaviour is that *anything* can happen, including confusing behaviour that doesn't seem to have any obvious logical explanation. Instead of trying to *understand* the undefined behaviour, you should try to *avoid* it. But if you really want to understand it, dissassemble the generated machine code and have a look at what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I thought so too, until I got ninjalj's comment. When there is a reason for collecting the strings (to de-duplicate them), there has to be a reason for not doing that with every string. I'm a bit noobish, so I'd like to try avoiding dissassembling...

Comment: @user1329846: the compiler can optimize things out. At high optimization levels, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler only emitted `"%c"` and `"asdf"` to the string table, completely optimizing out the `if` blocks.

Comment: Hrm..ok, has to be enough answer for me... Thank you guys!

Comment: And, interestingly enough, in my test with gcc 3.4.5 at -O2 optimization level, it not only completely optimizes out the `if` blocks, it also transforms the `printf("%c")` into a `putchar()`, emitting only `"asdf"` to the string table (which ends up in `.rodata` in ELF).